# When I run brew doctor, the following error is thrown

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, macos-monterey

**Warning:** "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

> `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3-config`
> `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8-config`

**Warning:** Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:

```
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/common.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/custom-space.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/garbage-collected.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/heap.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/accessors.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/api-constants.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/compiler-specific.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/finalizer-trait.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/gc-info.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/logging.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/persistent-node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/pointer-policies.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/internal/prefinalizer-handler.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/liveness-broker.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/macros.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/member.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/persistent.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/platform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/prefinalizer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/source-location.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/trace-trait.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/type-traits.h
  /usr/local/include/node/cppgc/visitor.h
  /usr/local/include/node/js_native_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/js_native_api_types.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform-export.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/v8-tracing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_api_types.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64-ARM/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-mips64/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/asm_avx2/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/buildinf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/no-asm/include/progs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/async.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asyncerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bio.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bioerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn_conf_asm.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn_conf_no-asm.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bnerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffererr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/camellia.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cast.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cms.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmserr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/comp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/comperr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conferr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/crypto.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cryptoerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ct.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cterr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dh.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dherr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dsaerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso_conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso_conf_asm.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso_conf_no-asm.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dtls1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/e_os2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ebcdic.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ec.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdh.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/engine.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/engineerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/evp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/evperr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/hmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/idea.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/kdf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/kdferr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/lhash.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md4.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md5.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/mdc2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/modes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/obj_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/objects.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/objectserr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ocsp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ocsperr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf_asm.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf_no-asm.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslv.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ossl_typ.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pemerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs12.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs12err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs7.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs7err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rand.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rand_drbg.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/randerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc4.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc5.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ripemd.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rsaerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/safestack.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/seed.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/sha.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/srp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/srtp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl3.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/sslerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/stack.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/store.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/storeerr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/symhacks.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/tls1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ts.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/tserr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/txt_db.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/uierr.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/whrlpool.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509_vfy.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509v3.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509v3err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/aix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/android-ifaddrs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/bsd.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/darwin.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/errno.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/linux.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/os390.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/posix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/stdint-msvc2008.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/sunos.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/threadpool.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/tree.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/unix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv/win.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-fast-api-calls.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-internal.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-platform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-util.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-value-serializer-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-version-string.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-wasm-trap-handler-posix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-wasm-trap-handler-win.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8config.h
  /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
```

**Warning**: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause formulae that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
python@3.9

**Warning**: Homebrew's "sbin" was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting your PATH for example like so:
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

**Warning**: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`:
/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
/usr/local/share/man/man8/prl_convert.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/prl_disk_tool.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/prlctl.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/prlexec.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/prlsrvctl.8

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here!

```
brew link --force --overwrite node
```

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/19.1.0...
Error: Could not symlink share/doc/node/gdbinit
/usr/local/share/doc/node is not writable.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please add this under comments.